# Display modal with Angular 9 and Bootstrap 4.5

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm using Angular 9 with Bootstrap 4.5. How can I display the bootstrap modal programmatically with fade effect? I found some articles but fade not work and backdrop not appears. Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe consider using ngx-bootstrap? It has a pretty solid modal available..

Comment: @MikeOne I didn't want to weigh down the application further, if it's not necessary. But if there are no alternatives I will use it.